# Non-convergence of a sequence implies 'consecutive' partial limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, multivariable-calculus, limsup-and-liminf

Let $n,d$ be fixed positive integers, and let $X^k=(x_1^k, \dots, x_n^k)$ be a bounded sequence, where $x_i^k \in \mathbb{R}^d$. (Every element of $X^k$ is an $n$-tuple of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$).

**Claim:** Suppose that $X^k$ has a **finite** number $N_0 \ge 2$ of accumulation points. Then there exist **distinct** accumulation points $Y=(y_1, \dots, y_n),Z=(z_1, \dots, z_n)$ and distinct subsequences $X^{k_j},X^{k_l}$ such that $X^{k_j} \to Y, X^{k_l} \to Z$ **and $k_l=k_j+1$.**

**How to prove this claim?**

I saw it mentioned in a paper without proof, so I assume there is an elementary solution.

Comment: In your first sentence, by $X^k,\ $ did you mean the *sequence* $\{X^k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\ ?$ And then your claim starts with "the sequence $\{X^k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ has a finite number of accumulation points..."? Is this what you mean? If so, then then with $n = 1, d=1,\ $ the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ is a counterexample to the result.

Comment: Your question also lacks details about what metric you're working in.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated the question accordingly. (Indeed, I forgot to mention that $X^k$ is divergent, or equivalently, that it has at least two different partial limits). And I assumed the standard topology (Euclidean metric) on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: No you need to define what it means for a sequence of n-tuples of points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ to converge to an n-tuple of points, $Y,$ in $\mathbb{R}^d.$

Answer (score 0):

In your claim:

1. $\{X^k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ must be bounded
2. the number of accumulation points of $\{X^k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ must be greater or equal than 2

I define   $\ \forall k \in \mathbb N \ , \ U^k=X^{k+1}-X^k$.
$\{U^k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded and has therefore at least one point of accumulation $U$.

If $U\neq 0$, there exists a subsequence $\{U^{\varphi(k)}\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ that converges to $U$. I extract from $\{X^{\varphi (k)}\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ a subsequence $\{X^{\varphi \circ \psi(k)}\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ that converges to $Y$. We have:
$\ \lim X^{\varphi \circ \psi(k)} = Y \ $ and $\ \lim X^{\varphi \circ \psi(k)+1} = Y +U$.

If the only point of accumulation of $\{U^k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is $0$, then, $\{U^k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $0$. I note $d$ the minimal distance between the points of accumulation of  $\{X^k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ and $\varepsilon =d/3$. There exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall p\geqslant N$, $X^p$ is in the union of $B(a,\varepsilon)$ where $a$ is a point of accumulation of  $\{X^k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ (otherwise, there would be another point of accumulation). There exists $M \geqslant N$ such that $\forall p\geqslant M \ , \|X^{p+1}-X^p\| < \varepsilon $. If we note $b$ the point of accumulation such that $X^M \in B(b,\varepsilon ) $, we can show by induction that $\forall p\geqslant M \ , X^{p} \in B(b,\varepsilon)$. But that would imply that $b$ is the only point of accumulation of  $\{X^k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$. There is a contradiction.

And the claim is proved .